# What are the advantages of beeline than hive CLI?

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

Could someone please explain what are the advantages of beeline than HIVE CLI?
I explored on this and found that

```
Beeline have the benefit to use LDAP/Kerberos authentication
```

But I couldn't get more insight on this. And with respect to OOZIE workflow will there be any difference b/w these two?

Also I found that Beeline is just a `HiveServer2 client`. So what is the difference between HiveServer1 and HiveServer2 ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: CLI = **fat** client. Slow to start, does all the query compilation/optimization/monitoring (and optionally, query execution) on the local machine. Considered as deprecated, but still useful for testing (custom UDF, custom SerDe, custom server-side configuration, new version of TEZ etc.) and debugging.

Comment: HiveServer2 is the **replacement** for HiveServer1 which has been retired *(incompatible changes in JDBC driver class, wire protocol etc.)*

Comment: Side note: Hive CLI is not compatible with the security features of Sentry & Ranger. That's why Cloudera and HortonWorks are trying to retire it.